# Access Images that match src

Tags: jquery

I am having 3 images. How can I access each one of them and then check the src to see if it matches a string? If the src matches a string, highlight the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to a little bit more functionality than just adding css classes use:

```
$('img[src="matchingString"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('MyCssClass');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(":img[src='matchString']").toggleClass('yourhighlightCSScalss')
```